# Changing ggpredict x-axis labels

Tags: ggplot2, axis-labels

I ran a model where I had to scale the continuous variable "year" to "1->15" (1st - 15th year) to get the intercept error under control, but now I'd like to change the x-axis labels back to there original form. I've seen that ggpredict can be altered like any ggplot(), but my method doesn't seem to be working. Is there something else I can try?

```
library(ggeffects)

ggpredict(mod, c("CYR.std", "Season")) %>% plot(rawdata = TRUE, jitter = .01) + 
  labs(title = "Predicted counts of Gulf Toadfish")
```

[image]

```
ggpredict(mod, c("CYR.std", "Season")) %>% plot(rawdata = TRUE, jitter = .01) + 
  labs(title = "Predicted counts of Gulf Toadfish", x = "Year", y = "Count") + 
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=c(2008, 2009, 2010, 2011, 
                              2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 
                              2016, 2017, 2018, 2019,
                              2020, 2021, 2022), 
                     labels=c('2008', '2009', '2010', '2011', 
                            '2012', '2013', '2014', '2015', 
                            '2016', '2017', '2018', '2019',
                            '2020', '2021', '2022')) + 
  theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 0))
```

[image]

My raw data is too large to share, but this could work:

```
n <- 10

#regression coefficients
beta0 <- 1
beta1 <- 0.2

#generate covariate values
x <- runif(n=n, min=0, max=1.5)

#compute mu's
mu <- exp(beta0 + beta1 * x)

#generate Y-values
y <- rpois(n=n, lambda=mu)

#data set
data <- data.frame(y=y, x=x)

model <- glm(y ~ x, data = data, family = poisson)

ggpredict(model, c("x")) %>% plot(rawdata = TRUE, jitter = .01) + 
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=c(2008, 2009, 2010), 
                     labels=c('2008', '2009', '2010'))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see a chain:

Data |> Model |> ggpredict |> Plot

The further down the chain, the more complex is the modification you have to make to alter some data.

###### Plot

Your approach started at the last point of the chain. `scale_x_...()` can only apply log transformations and such things, but doing a linear transformation, which would be necessary in your case to get `1:15` back to `2008:2022` is not possible (as far as I know, please correct me).

###### Data

So obviously, the best starting point to slip in transformed data is before modelling, e.g. finding a way for the model to handle your time variable accurately without linear transformation.
I can think of trying whether there are methods for date objects, and maybe converting your time variable to a date object.

I do not know the statistical side of this. Maybe the transformation you are doing to keep intercept in check is not necessary. Maybe there are other ways to represent a time variable accurately in your model.

But lets suppose it is necessary to linear transform the year variable prior to modeling.

###### Model

I think the best approach now would be to tamper with the model attributes and slip in some transformed data. I did try that, but my knowledge of poisson family models is nonexistent, and it only worked halfway. `ggpredict()` recognized the new data points, but something was wrong with the fitted curve. I think I should have manipulated some further model attributes which are later on used to plot the fit.

###### ggpredict

The next best entry point in the chain to slip in transformed data is within the `ggpredict` object, which is generated from the model. This is what I chose.

Using your example code:

```r
set.seed(123)

library(ggeffects)
library(ggplot2)

# Transform

range(x) # let's approximate the limits to [0; 1] for this example
# our known range of years is [2008; 2010]

# linear transformation
# I solved the equation system by: 
# 2008 = b0 + 0 * b1
# 2010 = b0 + 1 * b1

b0 <- 2008
b1 <- 2

x_transformed <- b0 + x * b1 

ggp <- ggpredict(model, c("x")) # create ggpredict object

unaltered <- plot(ggp, rawdata = TRUE) # test plot unaltered
unaltered # changes everytime it is plotted :/

# Alter the ggpredict object

# exchange all x with the transformed x in the ggpredict object
ggp$x <- sort(x_transformed) # this has to be sorted
attributes(ggp)$rawdata$x <- sort(x_transformed) # raw data is unsorted

# Final plot
plot(ggp, add.data = TRUE)
```

[image: plot]

##### Explanation

To transform the data ranging from 0 to 1 into a range from 2008 to 2010, we can use linear transformation `y = b0 + x * b1`. To obtain the parameters `b0` and `b1`, we have to solve a linear equation system with two equations.

Then we create the `ggpredict` object, which is essentially a data frame with some further attributes containing modeling information.

To slip in the transformed data, we have to put it at (at least) two places: Within the data frame, and within the further attributes.

To test if the fit maintains shape before and after manipulation, I saved an unaltered plot. What remains a mystery to me, and **maybe a critical point that renders this method garbage**: Everytime the plot is plotted, even without manipulations, the points are in different places. This seems very odd to me and I wonder if this is intended behaviour.

So I know that this solution is far from optimal. As I have stated, consider changing something further up the chain.